# What is the difference between new Exception() and new Exception { } in C#?

Tags: c#, exception

What is the difference between `new Exception()` and `new Exception { }` in C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a difference from `Exception` class, it is just a C# language structure to initilize properties, [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), for sample:

this:

```
Class obj = new Class();
obj.Message = "Message";
obj.IntProperty = 10;
```

is equal this:

```
Class obj = new Class () { Message = "Message", IntProperty = 10 };
```

*PS: When you initilize properties using `{ }` it is not on same constructor's scope. It executes after the constructor.*

Answer (score 4):

`new SomeType() { ... }` is an [*object initializer*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).
It allows you to set properties of the object.

Comment: you can put the properties within the () though too.

Comment: @puser: No; those are _constructor parameters_.

Comment: @puser: No, you can put arguments to the constructor in the `()`. That's not the same thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet What is the difference in `Exception("message")` and `Exception() { Message = "message" }` EDIT felipo edited his post to explain this

Comment: `Exception() { Message = "message" }` isn't legal code for some reason. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: @puser: That's a read-only property.

Comment: @puser Because the Message property is defined as `get` only: `public virtual string Message { get; }`